# Visual Studio Multi-device hybrid failed to fetch package information error

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, cordova, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I've installed the visual studio extension Multi-device hybrid, all is fine except when I run a new project with any of the the Cordova plugins enabled e.g. battery-status. I'm getting the error message below. But if I remove or disabled all the plugins it is working ok. Is anyone had an idea about the error dumps below or had experienced the same problem before? Thanks.

**Error Message**

Failed to fetch package information for org.apache.cordova.battery-status   C:\Mobile\CordovaApp\CordovaApp\EXEC    1   1   CordovaApp

**Visual Studio Output**

```
------ Adding plugin: org.apache.cordova.battery-status
1>  Calling plugman.fetch on plugin "org.apache.cordova.battery-status"
1>  
1>  C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\node_modules\q\q.js:126
1>                      throw e;
1>                            ^
1>EXEC : error : Failed to fetch package information for org.apache.cordova.battery-status
1>      at C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\registry\registry.js:32:20
1>      at Request.cb [as _callback] (C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\registry\registry.js:251:9)
1>      at self.callback (C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\request\index.js:148:22)
1>      at Request.emit (events.js:117:20)
1>      at ClientRequest.self.clientErrorHandler (C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\request\index.js:257:10)
1>      at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:95:17)
1>      at Socket.socketErrorListener (http.js:1551:9)
1>      at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
1>      at net.js:440:14
1>      at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
1>C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets(99,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli" build --platform "Android" --configuration "Debug" --projectDir . --projectName "CordovaApp" --language "en-US" --buildServerUrl "" --buildTarget "AndroidEmulator"" exited with code 8.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around by downloading the plugin itself and adding the folders into my project. 
First create a new folder called 'plugins' under your root project folder then copy the downloaded plugin (C:\myfile\cordova\plugins\org.apache.cordova.battery-status) under the plugins folder of your project. Build.

Comment: Plugman might fail if you are behind a corporate proxy that is preventing it from downloading the plugins. I was wondering if you knew that was the case?

Comment: Yes, I knew that could be the case as I am doing it at work, thanks. I just don't know how to set Plugman so that it could go through the corporate proxy. I was able to set it up in npm but don't know   where or how to set it up for Plugman.

Answer (score 0):

For set proxy settings on Plugman you must have to create a "config" file (without extension) in the **C:\Users\ -youruser-\ .plugman** folder, because plugman cant get itself npm proxy settings.

This config file are identical to .npmrc file of npm config:

```
proxy = http://username:passwords@proxyaddress:port#
https-proxy = http://username:passwords@proxyaddress:port#
```

Another way for set proxy is via console with:

```
plugman config set proxy http://username:passwords@proxyaddress:port#
```

This issue is tracked in jira for plugman.
[There is no way to set a proxy for plugman](https://issues.apache.org/jira/i#browse/CB-5017)